# jQuery Chosen breaks in firefox

Tags: jquery, forms, firefox, jquery-plugins

What's wrong with firefox's calculations while using the [Chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)? Other browsers work well.

[Example](http://projects.wavevision.cz/wvp/kodovani). Be patient, it takes some time to load the less stylesheets (not precompiled while testing).

Comment: Pekka: look at http://grab.by/aW1m & http://grab.by/aW1o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's wrong with firefox's calculations while using the Chosen plugin?

Calculation of the border/padding of the search field is wrong. In particular, this line:

```
sf_width = dd_width - get_side_border_padding(this.search_container) - get_side_border_padding(this.search_field)
```

In Chrome `dd_width` is 98 and the resulting `sf_width` value is 63. In Firefox `dd_width` is 100 and the resulting `sf_width` is 94. Given that *after* the page loads I get 8 for `get_side_border_padding(this.search_container)` and 27 for `get_side_border_padding(this.search_field)` I would guess that the calculation of the padding is done too early, most likely before the CSS file loaded. Probably making some assumptions about the load order that are true in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: I'm currently busy, will check your answer and let you know; anyway thanks a heap for your work

Comment: thanks for setting me on the right track, solution: put the call into `$(window).load()`, it's not ideal, but works